# Determine which jar file contain org.apache.lucene class file

Tags: java, jar, lucene

I am working on a search engine for searching (site is Tutorial Documentation) links & words/phrases contained in Site . I have a code which use `org.apache.lucene` package. How do I determine which jar file contains this package (class file is `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer`). I have downloaded `lucene-4.8.0` zip file from Apache mirror site. But It does not contains following classes

```
   org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
   org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser
   org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher;
```

My question How do I determine which jar file contains this package (containing all class files). Any guidance for Download site is appreciated. I have searched net but of no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Maven search](http://search.maven.org/): opt for advanced search and paste the class name. Then from the search results, pick the relevant version (4.8.0 in your case); this will show you the jar.

You can also search for both version and class name. Use `v` for version and `fc` for class name, e.g. the full query would look like as follows:

`v:"4.8.0" fc:"org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
<artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
<version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```